# Maven multi module project build: modules in local repo

Tags: maven, multi-module, maven-reactor

Suppose we have a multimodule project:

```
<modules>
  <module>first</module>
  <module>second</module>
</modules>
```

where `second` depends on `first` through `dependencies`.

If I run `mvn clean`***`package`***, does maven or reactor will put any of the modules to local repo anyway?

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no.

Here are the maven [lifecycle phases](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)

As you can see, `package` comes before `install`, so `install` wont be executed - nothing will go to your local repo, unless it was there already.

Comment: Actually I doubt. How is jar dependency then found to be added to final package or at least for running compile phase for `second` module?

Comment: I suspect if you run `package` on the second module you'll get an error like *Could not resolve dependencies for project* - have you tried it out?